# How to convert a string to a DatetimeWithNanoseconds format with python?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, nanotime

I have multiples strings representing timestamps. A few examples may be : `19551231` (%Y%m%d) or `20210216154500` (%Y%m%d%H%M%S). As you can see, the format may vary.

I'm looking for a way to convert all these different strings to a unique DatetimeWithNanoseconds format.

I know I can convert a timestamp to DatetimeWithNanoseconds using integers like this: `DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2020, 6, 22, 17, 1, 30, nanosecond=0)`.

Does that means that I have to manually parse every string I get to get the relevant integers ? Is there a better way to do this ? Like the way the function `strptime` works (using strings like `%Y%m%d` to determine the layout of the string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that from a `datetime` format it is easy to extract hours for example just by calling `date.hour` (same for year, month, etc).

Knowing this, the way to convert a string to a DatetimeWithNanoseconds format takes these 2 easy steps:

1. Convert the string to a datetime format:

```py
date = '19551231'
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d')
```

2. Convert to DatetimeWithNanoseconds:

```py
nano = DatetimeWithNanoseconds(date.year, date.month, date.day, date.hour, date.minute, date.second, nanosecond=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You offered 8- and 14-character example timestamps.
It appears you want to tack on 9 or more zeros,
converting them to uniform 23-character human-readable timestamps.
At that point it would be straightforward
to put it in [rfc 3339](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339) format and
call `from_rfc3339()` to obtain a [DatetimeWithNanoseconds](https://proto-plus-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/datetime_helpers.html#proto.datetime_helpers.DatetimeWithNanoseconds).

Consider using a simple `while` loop:

```
while len(ts) < 23:
    ts += '0'
return ts
```

A better way to accomplish the same thing:

```
return ts + '0' * (23 - len(ts))
```

EDIT

You will want a couple of helpers here.
Each one is unit testable, and offers a very simple API.

First one turns everything into uniform 23-char human-readable timestamps as I mentioned above.

Second would take the first 14 characters
and turn it into integer seconds since epoch.
Then tack on the nanoseconds.
I have something like this in mind:

```
import datetime as dt

def to_nanosec(stamp: str):
    assert 23 == len(stamp), stamp
    d = dt.datetime.strptime(stamp[:14], '%Y%d%m%H%M%S')
    return 1e9 * d.timestamp() + int(stamp) % 1e9
```

Equivalently that 2nd term could be `… + int(stamp[14:])`

Prefer `int(1e9)`, or `1_000_000_000`, if returning an `int` is important.

You certainly could break out character ranges
and put punctuation like `:` colon and `Z` between them
prior to calling `from_rfc3339()`,
but `.strptime()` might be more convenient here.

---

It's worth noting that numpy offers support
for [nanosecond precision](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html).

Comment: Unfortunately `from_rfc3339()` raise `ValueError`  because it does not accept my string `19551231` as the format does not match something like this : `2019-10-12T07:20:50.52Z`. Adding zero at the end of my string does not help my string to be rfc3339. Is there a way to convert it properly ?  `strptime()` does not help here because it convert `19551231` to `1955-12-31 00:00:00` which is still not accepted by the `from_rfc3339()` function.

Comment: Plus: the function `from_rfc3339()` returns a  `<class 'datetime.datetime'>` and not a
`<class 'proto.datetime_helpers.DatetimeWithNanoseconds'>`

Comment: Ouch! We get back a microsecond datetime, which won't support nanosecond? Sigh!